# Are there any modern languages which allow record level database access?

Tags: database

Folks who are familiar with COBOL and languages of that era may remember writing code in the style

```
While records exist in table A
   Read a record from table A
   If some condition
      Read records in table B until match found
      If some condition in record B
         Read a record in table C
         repeat ad nauseum
```

Our company is just starting to talk about updating our COBOL codebase to something more modern and any conversion would be much easier if we can continue to use record-level access, at least during the transition.  Rewriting everything in a new language *and* converting everything to SQL might be too much to undertake.

**Is there any modern language/database combination out there that will give us record-level access to our data?**

Comment: Right now, we're using COBOL on an IBM midrange running DB2.  We not only have record level access, but SQL access and all the other features of an enterprise database (journalling, triggers, etc).  We want a solution which keeps all of that yummy goodness.  Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on specific details of your situation.  Some form of record-level access should be available in most modern languages.  Here is an example in Python, assuming the data files are what Cobol would call "organization line sequential".  Notice the syntax is not too different from your example.  Depending on how the data files are structured, you might need to use something like tableB.seek(0) to restart searching at the start of the file.

```
tableA = open('tableA.txt', 'r')
tableB = open('tableB.txt', 'r')
tableC = open('tableC.txt', 'r')

for rowA in tableA:
    if some_Condition():
        for rowB in tableB:
            if rowA_rowB_match():
                if some_condition_in_record_B():
                    for rowC in tableC:
                        repeat ad nauseum
tableA.close()
tableB.close()
tableC.close()

def some_Condition():
    if x:
        return True
    else:
        return False

etc.
```

Comment: While that solution works for text files, I'm hoping to find a "real" database -- one that can handle large amounts of data efficiently and which we have the option of querying against with SQL.